# Why image picker not working with popup box?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a popup box where the user can select and upload an image. However, I am getting the following error. Below the error is the code I am using.
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on
channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

```
File _image;
final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  _imgFromCamera() async {
    final image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target version SDK is >= 29 you should add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Example:

```
<application
        android:label="stackoverflow"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />  // this line
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```

**Edit:**

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Container()
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:() async{

          File _image;
          final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
            final image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            setState(() {
              _image = File(image.path);
              print(_image.path);
            });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
image_picker: ^0.7.4
```

**Web**
[image: Picking Image]

[image: Image path in concole]

Comment: It's a web app. Do I still need to add it?

Comment: Then it is not necessary

Comment: @CameronBrowne I ran the snippet in flutter web and it works.

Comment: Did you add the other piece of code so the image can load? I am using a popup.

Comment: Nope. 
I reproduce the error and adding ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"``` solved the problem in Android when I ran the same code on web I got no error.
Have you checked if your package is up to date? and try running ```flutter clean```  and run the app

Comment: Yes, I clean the cache. I ran flutter clean and restart the app and I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

- Try flutter clean
- get package
- then flutter build